# Using salesforce as saml 2.0 idp provider

Tags: salesforce, saml-2.0

I am trying to configure salesforce as idp for my saml2.0 based sp. I have enabled domain, sso, created connected app with appropriate profile. with all this I am able to login into sp using using idp initiated url. idp initiated salesforce url correctly, my sp gets correct saml response. but when I try to use sp initiated flow and post saml request to salesforce endpoint, it give error "Insufficient Privileges". Have anyone faced this issue or knows something about this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue. Apparently salesforce doesn't give what is the error. Here I was using redirect request sending to post url.